# use react with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I started learning React and It's really amazing, I enjoy coding with React.

In official doc said that React can be used for UI only.

> React is a JavaScript library for creating user interfaces by Facebook
>   and Instagram. Many people choose to think of React as the V in MVC.

So, Can I use `React` with `Angular.js` for `UI`? Is that a good idea or bad? (why?)

Googling, I found lib called [ngReact](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact). It allows use React Components in Angular.

What you think about this? Give me an idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it at all - just pick one of them! There's a whole ecosystem around React to make apps, and Angular has it's own, using React to render a view in Angular just seems wasteful and pointless as Angular is perfectly good at doing that - by using both you are crippling the features of either (not to mention bloating your page with JS)

Comment: i am flagging the question as it is mainly opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using ngReact for an application which is written on angular.

We had to switch the view for some parts of the applications to react because of the constant data changes and is expensive for digest cycles.

angularjs is good to handle the ui for most applications unless you are looking at rendering a lot of data. Even in that case if the data is not changing you can use single binding of angular. If you have data that is constantly changing your view might get slow in angular that is the only downside with existing angular versions.

That being said using ngReact can become tricky at times. Mainly communicating with angular services, basic directives like ui-sref and react nested components.

Be sure of the reason for using ngReact.

using react, angular and even a combination should be more than a personal preference.

Comment: Will you suggest to use Angular 1.5 which brings the component concept in Angular 1.x in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Ive recently my self started to learn React. And you are completly right React is just for UI and dosent support any Model / Controlers.

But mixing React & Angular for me seems a bit odd? Angular got its own template engine with their directvies (Angular 1.xx). So it would be a bit akward to match these too frame works.

If i was you i would look into this thing called Redux, witch is another way of doing flux architecture. This is also the architecture that React is initially thought upon. And its really powerful.

Here is a couple of nice to have to get into:
https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux - This is a free course on Redux (witch you want to use with storing data for you react views)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually interoperate Angular and React really nicely with https://github.com/bcherny/ngimport. My team and I have used it successfully on our 10k file hybrid Angular+React project - let me know if I can answer any questions!